# How to make an option to switch between languages inside the app

Tags: android, localization, settings

I have 6 different languages in my Android app and I want to create an option to choose the language for the app.
I saw that code but the app resets the language after restart:

```
public void setLocale(String lang) { 
myLocale = new Locale(lang); 
Resources res = getResources(); 
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics(); 
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration(); 
conf.locale = myLocale; 
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm); 
Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class); 
startActivity(refresh); 
finish();
}
```

What can I do to keep the language that the user chose?

Comment: Save the language in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: How can I do it (I mean, I have 6 languages)?

Comment: Save a key in `SharedPreferences` which is the identifier for the selected language and load it when your app opens.

Comment: OK. Can you write the answer with code so I will be able to accept it? @mgcaguioa

Comment: Check this link on how to use `SharedPreferences` >> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: There is no a better way to keep the chosen language?

Comment: @ItielMaimon: Please don't expect people to write code for you on stackoverflow! There is no other way, as far as I know for doing this, unless you are using the default language of the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
String sharedPrefName = "your_preference_name"
String key = "selected_language"

// save the selected language
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(key, "english"); // replace "english" with user's selected language
editor.commit();

// retrieve selected language
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String language = sharedpreferences.getString(key, "english"); // replace "english" with your app's default language

// load the app with the language selected...
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine, but when the app retrieve the selected language why I need to put the app's default language?

Comment: The default language will be used by your app when the language is not yet set by your user